# Entity Framework: Any or All - Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am trying to do something like this:

```
from t in ent.myEntities
where SelectedProperties == null || SelectedProperties.Any(le => le == t.Entity)
select t
```

basically trying to cover 2 cases. accepting an empty list, should return all entities, or filter on the list if it is supplied.

above actually does work when i supply the list, however in the case when it is null i get:

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'. Only primitive types ('such as
>   Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context

also tried using this with a string array:

```
where arr == null || arr.Contains(t.Entity)
```

is it possible to have such a condition without having to build a predicate (which is a bigger effort)?

Comment: The EF LINQ support is very poor. Such a shame because LINQ to SQL can do all those things, but it is deprecated.

Comment: that is a shame. hopefully some more support is coming in EF 4.5

Comment: Is `SelectedProperties` a `List<T>` with `T` a primitive type, like `int`? Or what type is it exactly?

Comment: yep, it's a List<string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to *try* using the list in a simpler way:

```
where SelectedProperties == null || SelectedProperties.Contains(t.Entity)
```

It may well not work, but it's worth a try. Otherwise, if this is *really* your whole query, I'd just write it as:

```
var query = SelectedProperties == null 
            ? ent.myEntities
            : ent.myEntities.Where(t => SelectedProperties.Contains(t.Entity));
```

EDIT: Okay, if you have to use `Any`, and have lots of these to compose, you can do it like this:

```
var query = ent.myEntities;
if (SelectedProperties != null)
{
    query = query.Where(t => SelectedProperties.Any(x => x == t.Entity));
}
if (SomethingElse)
{
    query = query.Where(...);
}
// etc
```

Comment: thanks Jon! i was not able to use .Contains at all, as it doesn't seem to be supported by EF.  as for the 2nd example its not ideal, because i have more than one of these properties to check.. so i'd need to create a separate query for every combination of supplied elements.

Comment: @SonicSoul: No, you can compose queries easily. I'll edit the post to show  you what I mean.

Comment: thank Jon! the conditional around the query will work, but the sucky part is that if i am checking 2 variables for null, i'd need to define this query 4 times. (check if a not b or a&b or b not a or not b not a) etc.. not ideal.. i'd be probably better off with a predicate builder.. which i implemented in another projects.. was just hoping i wouldn't have to resort to that with such a seemingly easy use case as above.. really don't think EF is all that usable

Comment: @SonicSoul: Why would you need to define it four times? What's wrong with the code in my edit, using the composition of queries?

Comment: the point is that i could only use a supplied list if its not null (since EF doesn't seem to be able to do the null check in query if the other side of || is a List.Any).. so i'd need to have a separate query for all combinations of available parameters. separate query for when both are supplied, one is supplied, the other, or none

Comment: @SonicSoul: Not at all. Again, my edit shows how you can do this using composition *without* having a separate query for every permutation. You just keep conditionally calling `Where` with the extra conditions.

Comment: oh! didn't realize you can append the query this way!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using EF5, something like this will fix the issue:

```
ent.myEntities.ToList().Where(t => SelectedProperties == null || SelectedProperties.Contains(t.Entity));
```